# Open xml sdk with Excel Add In

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in, openxml-sdk

I want to use open xml sdk in excel add-In.
But

```
SpreadsheetDocument.Open()
```

method fails as the subject document is currently open.

To describe more.

I open any excel document, and have my custom excel add-in in it.from the add-in I want to gather some data from the spreadsheet using open xml sdk.

Is there any way around this, to use open xml sdk in excel add-ins and access current workbook using the same?

Comment: Why do you need to use Open XML SDK when you can use the Excel object model?

Answer (score 0):

You can gather data from Excel using the Excel Object Model also, and is far more convenient. But as you are using Open XML SDK and calling it to open the same document again from within Excel, you should Open it as ReadOnly.

```
SpreadsheetDocument.Open(path, isEditable)
```

Set the current spreadsheet's full path in `path` and set `isEditble` to `False`

Get more info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc562356%28v=office.15%29.aspx)